# How to mix content for logged users and not logged users in Symfony 2.3 or superior

Tags: php, symfony, web

What is the best approach to do this in Symfony 2.3 or superior:

I have a web page that can be posted in a public area or in a secured area.

When the user open the secured web page version, lets say /SecureArea/page1 is able only to see the content and do more thing but when a user is not logged in, they can see the same content in /PublicArea/page1 but can only see the content not doing anything else at least of course they login.

Securing a web page in Symfony is quite easy , you put your web page inside a secure area, but what I am trying to do is to have the same version of the webpage in both, users are able to see the same content but can only do more things if they are logged into the system. I don't want to repeat myself and create two different versions of the same page.

Comment: I forgot to mention a very important thing: I am pre rendering the page, so the web page is being rendered as static HTML instead of running the twig file for better performance. That means that i cannot use {% if is_granted ... since that is true only when I render the content.

Comment: Don't forget to pick the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case you can make decision what to do based on `is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` in twig, which basically checks if current user is logged in, so example would be like:

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
    {# do something that only logged in users could see #}
{% else %}
    {# do something that unauthenticated users can see #}
{% endif %}
```

If you want to check if user is logged in or not in controller instead:

```
if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    // user logged in
} else {
    // not logged in
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan. I forgot to mention a very important thing: I am pre rendering the page, so the web page is being rendered as static HTML instead of running the twig file for better performance. That means that i cannot use {% if is_granted ... since that is true only when I render the content.

Comment: You mean you're using php templating engine instead of twig? How do you render templates?

Comment: What i am doing is: I am using a symfony command to render the content, then I store the html and that is the content that I am presenting to the users

Comment: Ok, I see. Then, what about generating seperate html files for logged in and not logged in users, and based on the example (using checker in controller) I wrote above, return appropriate html content? Can't think of better way right now.